# operator precedence and associativity with Math.Floor(Math.Random())

Tags: javascript

I understand how the code works, in terms of the results it gives.  First, it gets a random number, and, second, using Math.floor() it rounds down the results of Math.Random. Therefore, it's moving from right to left through the code.

```
Math.floor(Math.Random * num);
```

In the JavaScript Reference at this  [url](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/precedence_operators.shtml) and shown in the image below
[image: url]

it says that, for dot and parentheses, the associativity is "left to right". However, based on the code I excerpted above, I'd say it was "right to left." Please explain

Comment: associativity != execution order

Comment: right to left would mean: `Math.(floor(num))` with error "floor is undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [associativity of operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) has nothing to with their execution order, but how they are parsed.

Associativity "Left to right" means that `a.b.c === (a.b).c !== a.(b.c)`.

When you have a function invocation, of course the arguments are evaluated first (at least in non-lazy languages like JS) - this is also defined in the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.3).

What happens here is:

- `Math.floor(Math.Random * num);` is parsed into an [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), according to the rules of operator precedence and associativity:

```
-\ invocation
 +-\ function: member operator
 | +-- base: variable "Math"
 | +-- property: "floor"
 +-\ arguments list
   +-\ first: Multiplication
     +-\ left operand: member operator
     | +-- base: variable "Math"
     | +-- property: "Random"
     +-- right operand: variable "num"
```

- When evaluated, it happens top-down. The invocation first evaluates its function, calling the member operator on `Math` and `floor`. As this evaluates to a vaild function, it proceeds evaluating the arguments. The multiplication will first fetch its left operand, getting *undefined* from the member operator on `Math` and `Random`; then it fetches the value of the variable `num`. This results in `NaN`, and now the floor-function will be called with that, returning `NaN` again.

Answer (score 1):

A function cannot be called without its arguments being resolved. This not not a matter of operator precedence (but execution order). The reason why a function call is left-associative is to make e.g. the following call work properly:

```
foo.bar.baz()
```

With the operator being left-associative this is equal to

```
((foo.bar).baz)()
```

which is equal to the original code. If it was right-associative you'd get the following:

```
foo.(bar.(baz())
```

That would obviously do something totally different which would most likely not work at all.

By the way, the function call is on a different precedence level than the member operators. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) for a better reference about this topic than the one you linked in your question.